# Knex migration and seed in NodeJS project

Tags: web, knex.js

I am a beginner in web development. In my learning journey, I develop a boilerplate to serve as a template for other web apps (see the app: https://github.com/web-needle/sappio). I try to configure knex for the first time, but it is not collaborative.

I ask you to avoid assumptions you my know and may lack in these instructions. My development environment is Linux. The configuration file is available [here](https://github.com/web-needle/sappio/blob/main/config/knexfile.js).

Firstly, I write [migrations](https://github.com/web-needle/sappio/blob/main/db/migrations/create_users_table.js) and [seeds](https://github.com/web-needle/sappio/blob/main/db/seeds/seed_users_table.js) for the `users` table. Then, I run the command `knex migrate:make create_users_table` on the terminal. The below log is the undesired output:

```
Using environment: development
Using environment: development
Using environment: development
Failed to resolve config file, knex cannot determine where to generate migrations
The "path" argument must be of type string. Received null
TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "path" argument must be of type string. Received null
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:387:5)
    at validateString (node:internal/validators:162:11)
    at Object.resolve (node:path:1098:7)
    at /home/brunolnetto/github/web-needle/sappio/node_modules/knex/lib/migrations/migrate/MigrationGenerator.js:77:19
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at MigrationGenerator._absoluteConfigDirs (/home/brunolnetto/github/web-needle/sappio/node_modules/knex/lib/migrations/migrate/MigrationGenerator.js:71:24)
    at MigrationGenerator._ensureFolder (/home/brunolnetto/github/web-needle/sappio/node_modules/knex/lib/migrations/migrate/MigrationGenerator.js:28:23)
    at MigrationGenerator.make (/home/brunolnetto/github/web-needle/sappio/node_modules/knex/lib/migrations/migrate/MigrationGenerator.js:20:16)
    at Migrator.make (/home/brunolnetto/github/web-needle/sappio/node_modules/knex/lib/migrations/migrate/Migrator.js:315:27)
    at Command.<anonymous> (/home/brunolnetto/.nvm/versions/node/v16.18.0/lib/node_modules/knex/bin/cli.js:231:12)
```

Comment: Maybe you just need to specify where to find your config, migration and seed files [per the documentation](https://knexjs.org/guide/migrations.html#migration-cli)

Comment: It is there already :-/ : https://github.com/web-needle/sappio/blob/main/config/knexfile.js